# EMF- how to delete programmatically an instance from a model

Tags: eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, ecore

I have created my metamodel, called `WFG.ecore`.

With ATL I managed to transform a bpmn2 file in a WFG model. The ATL transformation gives to the object `WorkFlow`, that is the container of all the other objects in WFG.

Now I would like to modify the object `WorkFlow` programmatically in Java, but I can not.

How can I delete an object instance from its container, and so from all the occurrences?

Below there is an example with instances

```
            gateways
           +--------->+----------+
           |          |Gateway_1 |
           ♦          +----------+
+-----------+              ^
|WorkFlow_1 |              | nextGateway 0..1
+-----------+              |
           ♦           +---------+
           |           | Node_1  |
           +---------->+---------+
           nodes
```

I would like to delete the instance `Gateway_1`, so that it's no more contained in `WorkFlow_1`, and so that `Node_1.getNextGateway->null`.  I tried to do
`WorkFlow_1.getGateways().remove(Gateway_1)` but doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The naive answer is to use `EcoreUtil.delete()` or the `Delete` command. Both of these remove the `EObject` from its container and remove (i.e. null out) any cross references. In general, though, you don't want to do it that way for the following reasons:

1. Child references. Though `EcoreUtil.delete(Gateway_1)` will remove `Gateway_1` from its container and from the `Node_1` reference, it won't remove any cross references to children of `Gateway_1` ***EVEN THOUGH THEY ALSO WILL BE DELETED*** from their container. So you could end up with dangling references to nonexistent objects that were children of `Gateway_1`.
2. Performance. There's no reliable way to find cross references efficiently. That means that every EObject in your model will be checked to see if it has a cross reference to `Gateway_1` so that cross reference can be deleted. That makes `EcoreUtil.delete()` an *O(n)* operation where *n* is the number of EObjects in your model.

The best solution is some combination of bidirectional references and reference maps. Either `Gateway_1` should know who is cross referencing it, or that information should be accessible elsewhere. That way you can explicitly remove all references to `Gateway_1` in an efficient and complete manner.

This answer closely follows [this blog post, EMF Dos and Don'ts #11, by Maximilian Koegel and Jonas Helming](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2015/05/26/emf-dos-and-donts-11/).

By the way, `EcoreUtil.remove()` does NOT do the cross reference removal, it just removes the EObject from its container.

Comment: Since version 2.4, you also have another version `delete(EObject eObject, boolean recursive)`:

"If recursive true, contained children of the object that are in the same resource are similarly removed from any features that reference them"

Answer (score -1):

```
DeleteCommand.create(editingDomain, Collections.singleton(Gateway_1));
editingDomain.getCommandStack().execute(command);
```

And for Node_1:

```
Node_1.setNextGateway(null);
```

Comment: So I have to manually delete the recursive references, it is not enough just delete an object from the container. Is there a way to automatically do that? Manually delete the references is much error-prone, especially if I will add new references in the future, and it's hard to remember to add also the relative deleting code. thank you

Comment: EcoreUtil delete methods can help: http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.5.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/EcoreUtil.html

Comment: DeleteCommand removes cross references automatically. You don't need to do that second part, Node_1.setNextGateway(null);